# Transmit MediaStream data via http

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, http-put

Is there any way to send the data inside a `MediaStream` acquired by `getUserMedia` via HTTP (eg. a streaming PUT request) instead of WebRTC?

I like to store the captured video onto the server, so none of the peer-to-peer features of WebRTC connection are needed. I do not like to use a WebRTC peer on the server due to it's complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The new MediaRecorder API (availabe in Firefox and Chrome Canary) can do that. See https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/
You basically replace handleDataAvailable with your own implementation which pushes chunks to the server